# When to use Switch and If else statement?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

(Sorry for my bad English)

Hi everyone!

I'm new to JS!

I'm learning about Switch currently and a little bit confused about it.

More specifically, when should I use "true" in the switch and when to use the original variable name!

For example, this is my code!

```
var age = 10;

    switch(true){
            
        case age>=10:
        console.log('He is a kid');
        break;
            
        case age>10 && age<=20:
        console.log('He is a teenager');
        break;
            
        case age>=20 && age<=30:
        console.log('He is a young man');
        break;
            
    
        case age>30:
        console.log('He is a man')
    
        

            
            
    }
```

This works totally fine if I do switch(true) but if I do what most people say switch(age), this doesnt work!

So i'm a bit confused when to use what!

My guessing, if I'm doing greater than, equal to and less than type of things with numbers, then you you true in the swithc!

Can anyone please help?

Comment: switch is really for exact matches. What is there works, but is not a good practice. The code really should be `if/else if/else`

Comment: "*when should I use "true" in the switch*" basically never. It's a very bad pattern as it leads to a harder to maintain and understand code.

Comment: Logic issue you have is everything is > 10 on first check so they will fall into that check.

Comment: I disagree that this is harder to maintain and understand. I find it infinitely easier than a series of nested if else if...s and much cleaner.  The logic in the example is flawed as others have pointed out though.

Comment: @MikeFeltman you don't need to nest `if` statements but chain them. And besides, for *this* case where the condition space is nicely sliced into discrete chunks, you don't even need `if`s but just turn it into a table/map/collection of conditions and executions which gives you an even neater way to encapsulate and maintain the logic.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you had a logical error in the first case expression, you like the check for **smaller or equal**.

For the next following case expressions, you need only single condition, because you checked before and the conditions breaks the statement.

For the last part, you could take `default` which is only called if no condition is right.

```js
var age = 10;

switch (true) {
    case age <= 10:
        console.log('He is a kid');
        break;

    case age <= 20:
        console.log('He is a teenager');
        break;

    case age <= 30:
        console.log('He is a young man');
        break;

    default:
      console.log('He is a man')
}
```

Finally the standard approach (and this is questionalble, too), is to use a function with `if` statements and exit early, like

```
function getType(age) {
    if (age <= 10) return 'He is a kid';
    if (age <= 20) return 'He is a teenager';
    if (age <= 30) return 'He is a young man';
    return 'He is a man';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as stated in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch):
The switch statement evaluates an expression, **matching** the expression's value to a case clause, and executes statements associated with that case, as well as statements in cases that follow the matching case.

meaning that the switch statement is for exact matches only. there is no use and no way telling how it will go when using switch(true).

this answer  is valid for most programming languages and not only to JS.

Comment: I am new to JS so its pretty hard to get you. Can you please tell what do you mean by expressions  and exact matches only ? i assume you're saying exact matches like name = "johnson" so we can use this in the switch but not when we're like using greater than and less than!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

The **switch** matches its "expression" to the **case** "expression" clause using the strict comparison === and transfers control to that clause.

If your case expressions are to contain other operations (less than, higher, or other complex operation) then you can use **"switch (true) {"** and do a normal comparison at the "case" level.